# Why can't my Rspec integration tests find my modules?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'd like to be able to call `login_as_admin` and `login_as_customer` at any point in any spec file.

I have a directory full of integration specs:

```
/spec/features/area_spec.rb
/spec/features/assignment_spec.rb
/spec/features/etc…
```

Each of which starts with:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec_macros'
```

I also have `/spec/spec_help.rb`, which includes:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/rspec_macros"
```

And I have `/spec/rspec_macros.rb`, which includes:

```
module RspecMacros
  def login_as_admin
    etc…
  end
  def login_as_customer
    etc…
  end
end
```

Why, then, do I get the following error at the Rspec command line?

```
 Failure/Error: login_as_customer
 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `login_as_customer' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_2:0x007fd99f471f50>
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to share a bunch of functions between your different specs, is that right?

Comment: Indeed. I'd like to be able to call login_as_admin etc at any point in any spec file.

Comment: updated text to make that clear, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you either need to make these functions in spec helper or include the modules in your tests.

To include the modules you can do something like this:

```
module RspecMacros 
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def login_as_customer
      ... 
    end
  end
end

require 'rspec_macros'
describe MyCoolTest do    
  include RspecMacros
end
```

You may find it easier to just make them functions in spec helper.  You can just add:

```
def login_as_customer
   ....
end
```

to the end of spec_helper.rb

Comment: Thanks. How do I make them functions in spec helper?