# Can't access included module methods from view when running RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I have a ProductController, that includes a module with some helper methods:

```
class ProductController < ApplicationController
  include ProductItemHelper

  def item
    @product = Product.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end
end
```

and the module looks like this:

```
module ProductItemHelper

  def seoify(text)
    unless text.blank?
      "#{text.titleize} | "
    end
  end

end
```

and then in my view, I call the helper method like this:

```
content_for :meta_title do
  "#{seoify(@product.title)}"
end
```

which works as it should when I run the app in any environment, but when I try to visit the page in an RSpec test, it hits the controller and the view, but errors out with:

```
undefined method `seoify' for #<#<Class:0x0000000a6a0a18>:0x0000000b726e50>
```

and I can't understand why. I've tested calling the method from the controller, which works fine, @product.title has several different methods applied to it at different points throughout the view, so I'd like to be able to reference the module methods from the view.

Is there some RSpec configuration I'm missing to make them accessible?

Comment: view / controller, hopefully they are not mixed

Comment: It looks like I need to explicitly include those methods in RSpec, so I've created a file within spec/support called utilities.rb and included that - and it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945164/why-cant-my-rspec-integration-tests-find-my-modules?rq=1) got me on the right track, I just needed to include the methods within a helper file in my spec directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use built-in controller's class method `helper` to require and include helper

```
class ProductController < ApplicationController
  helper :product_item
```

http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper